# I am not able to use index of a particular character in a string using a for loop in Python. It's giving an index error

Tags: python, python-3.x

my Python code:

```
x = ["abc", "e", "i"]

for i in x:
    for j in x[i]:
        print(x[i][j])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
print(x[i][j])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So essentially the problem lies with the line `for j in x[i]:`

Desired output:

```
a
b
c
e
i
```

Comment: It seems you don't know what iterating on a list does : add a `print(i)` you'll see what it contains

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over something, the iteration variable is assigned to the elements in the iterable, not the indices.  You therefore don't need to use the subscript `[]` operator to reference the elements; just use them directly:

```
x = ["abc", "e", "i"]

for i in x:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

Using more descriptive variable names can help you keep track of what you're iterating over in each loop:

```
for word in x:
    for letter in word:
        print(letter)
```

If you did want to iterate by index, you'd do that by building a `range` that has the `len` of each iterable, and then iterating over the ints in the range (which will correspond to the indices of the iterable that you got the `len` from):

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        print(x[i][j])
```

There's no benefit to doing that here, though, and it just makes the code harder to read.  Most of the time you want to iterate over the elements directly.